# How to solve the surface integral $\int\int_{S}\{(\frac{2x}{\pi}+\sin(y^2))x+(e^z-\frac{y}{\pi})y+(\frac{2z}{\pi}+\sin^2y)z\}d\sigma$?

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

> Consider the unit sphere $S=\{(x,y,z)\in {R^3}:x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ and the unit normal vector $\bar{n}$ at each point $(x,y,z)$ on $S$. Then the value of the surface integral $$\int\int_{S}\{(\frac{2x}{\pi}+\sin(y^2))x+(e^z-\frac{y}{\pi})y+(\frac{2z}{\pi}+\sin^2y)z\}d\sigma$$ is____?

Ok so this is what I tried to do:

Since this is a surface integral over a sphere, therefore I thought to convert it into a triple integral by using Gauss's Theorem, viz,

$$\int\int_{S}(f ~dy ~dz+g~dz~dx+h~dx~dy)=\int\int\int_{E}(f_x+g_y+h_z)~dx~dy~dz$$

So $f=(e^z-\frac{y}{\pi})y+(\frac{2z}{\pi}+\sin^2y)z$, $~g=0$ (since there is no term involving $~dz~dx$), and $h=(\frac{2x}{\pi}+\sin(y^2))x$. At this point I am stuck. This way doesnot provide any sensible conclusion.

Can anyone provide some other way? How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ right?

Comment: Change to spherical coordinates.

Comment: @JackyChong yes. Thanks.

Comment: @lightxbulb the integrand inside the double integral?

Comment: All variables. And the limits. And the Jacobian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall

\begin{align}
\iint_\Sigma \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\ dS = \iiint_D \operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\ dV
\end{align}
Here $\mathbf{F} = (\frac{2x}{\pi}+\sin(y^2))\mathbf{i}+(e^z-\frac{y}{\pi})\mathbf{j}+(\frac{2z}{\pi}+\sin^2(y))\mathbf{k}$ where $\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F} = \frac{3}{\pi}$.

Comment: Ok so the volume of the sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi$, which will give the value of the triple integral to be 4. Thanks.